# hierarchal data paging in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hierarchical-data

I've data in hierarchal format which can be nested up to an unkown level (imagine threaded comments or products with nested categories).

This data is currently displayed in a tree like format using Razor, HTML DIVs and CSS. Now, there is a need to implement some form of paging to it. Please share your thoughts on paging an hierarchal data like:

**Data Loading Logic**
Load specific count of top level comments (with their children populated till leaf) OR some way count till leaf levels OR ???

**Paging Action**
What can be a good approach for such loading - Load on Scroll, numbered paging etc.?

As an additional info, I'm using NHibernate with repository pattern and get flat List of all objects. However each object can be drilled down as well (flat list is inclusive of children. Roots have parent as null)

Please provide your thoughts on above queries or post links to pages where similar requirement implemented.

thanks